# Case statement in Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I'm getting   the below error can someone please help me.

```
2015-04-16 12:17:26,330 ERROR [http-8080-Processor23] ErrorCounter - line 1:225: unexpected token: -
2015-04-16 12:17:26,345 ERROR [http-8080-Processor23] ErrorCounter - line 1:253: unexpected token: else
2015-04-16 12:17:26,345 ERROR [http-8080-Processor23] ErrorCounter - line 1:327: expecting CLOSE, found '.'
```

Here is my query..

```
public List<DwnGactABForFile> getDwnGactABForFile(String sqlCrit)
            throws DataAccessException {        
        String sql = "select new com.compass.beactive.vo.DwnGactABForFile(a.gaaAccnum, a.gaaSrccode, a.gaaBuysellcode, b.gabScnetamt, a.gaaProcessdate," 
            + " (case when cast (a.gaaTransnetamt as float) = 0 then (cast(replace(a.gaaTransmarketvalue ,'-','0') as decimal(15,2))) else (cast(replace(a.gaaTransnetamt,'-','0') as decimal(15,2)))end)as a.gaaTransnetamt," 
            + " b.gabTradecurrcode, b.gabDescline01, b.gabDescline02, b.gabDescline03, "
            + " b.gabDescline04, b.gabDescline05, b.gabDescline06, b.gabDescline07, b.gabDescline08, b.gabDescline09, b.gabDescline10,"
            + " b.gabDescline11, b.gabDescline12) "
            + " from DwnGactA a, DwnGactB b "
            + " where a.gaaIdent = b.gabIdent "
            + " and a.gaaIdseqnum = b.gabIdseqnum "
            + sqlCrit
            + " order by a.gaaProcessdate ";
        Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("Full sql query" +sqlCrit);
        return query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the above issue

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(a.gaaTransnetamt, '0.000'), a.gaaTransmarketvalue)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `replace()` is a valid JPQL or HQL function. If your version of Hibernate supports JPA 2.1, you could try calling a native DB function using the `function()` function. For example, this should work with MS SQL Server:

```
function("replace", a.gaaTransmarketvalue , '-', '0')
```